# Alternative Hypothesis

Tags: probability, statistics

I am facing a little problem is this question. Can somebody please help e here

A sample of 500 drivers was asked whether or not they speed while driving. The following table gives a two-way classification:

[image]

We wish to test whether gender and speeding are related at the 1% significant level.

State the null and alternative hypothesis for this test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your counts are so small, you can use Fisher's exact test on a computer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test  The programming language R for example has Fisher's exact test implemented as a function you can call. The null hypothesis is that gender and speeding are independent, and the alternative hypothesis is that they are related (2-sided hypothesis, either males speed more or females speed more). You can also find webistes online that will calculate the p-value for your table using Fisher's exact test.

Just looking at your table, it is obvious that you will find that males speed more at $1\%$ significance level.

Comment: Sir how can we calculate the critical value for the test?

Comment: @HaniAbdullah If you use the chi-squared distribution approximation you can get the critical value from an  online calculator. For Fisher's exact test, the critical value for the table entries depends on the table, and there's no known formula for the critical value. You simply write down all tables in order from most extreme to least extreme, adding up probabilities of tables until the last table that leaves the sum of probabilities less than $1\%$, and then all the tables you added are the significant tables, and all the other tables are not significant.

Comment: sir actually i am new in this. don't know about it much so can u please help me elaborating please

Comment: H0: µ = 500 -->null hypothesis
H1: µ < 500 -->alternative hypothesis. Is that correct sir?

Comment: Sir i found P-value using an online calculator to be 0.0218. is that correct sir?